# Visual Studio branch compare giving false positives. Identical files are marked as different

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control, compare, branch

I have a project in VS 2017 using default TFS version control with a main trunk and several branches. Most branches maintain the parent-child relationship, some occasionally get baseless merged.

When I compare any of the branches to each other, either parent or sibling, I get several hundred false positives, where the the compare window marks them as "Different", but when the individual files are compared, they are identical. The encoding appears to be the same as well. It basically renders the compare useless because I'm wading through hundreds of false positives.

I've tried the default VS compare, and now I've changed to Kdiff3, both give the same result.

The only other thing I can think of is the Filter string in the compare window, which is:

```
!bin\;!bld\;!ClientBin\;!Debug\;!obj\;!AppPackages\;!Release\;!TestResults\;!*.*~!*.appx!*.appxrecipe;!*.cache!*.cer!*.dbmdl!*.dll!*.docstates!*.docstates.suo;!*.err!*.exe!*.ilk!*.ipch!*.lastbuildstate!*.lce!*.ldf!*.lib!*.log!*.mdf!*.msscci!*.ncb!*.obj!*.opensdf!*.pch!*.pdb!*.pri!*.res!*.resources!*.sdf!*.suo!*.swp!*.temp!*.tfOrig*!*.tlog!*.tmp!*.trx!*.user!*.unsuccessfulbuild!*.v11.suo!*.vcxproj.user!*.vsix!*.vsmdi!*.vspscc!*.vssettings!*.vssscc!*.wrn!*.xap;!.metadata\
```

I didn't set that, I was given this project and that's how it was already setup. Since I was handed this project, the compare has always been broken in this manner.

How can I figure out why the false positives are being given, and how to fix them so that I can get a proper compare.

**Images: Compare | Files are the same | Encoding is the same**
[image]
[image]
[image]